# Is "day use" the correct term for hotel rooms booked without overnight stay?

Tags: word-usage

I'm trying to find the correct English word or term for hotel rooms that you can book by the hour. For example, if a hotel with Spa rents its room for just the afternoon too.

Is "day use" the correct term? Doing a quick web search there are some hotels which use this term, but I'm not sure if it's just because they're French or Italian and just made it up in order to have a simple term which people from other countries can understand.

Comment: It's one of the politer terms.

Comment: A hotel that "charges by the hour" is used so frequently to describe a hotel that caters to prostitutes that I would avoid using that as a description in any way... whether it is a correct description or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. The term 'day use' is the correct term which refers to those who do not intend to use the room for a full day. Mind you, almost all international hotels do not rent rooms by the hour, while some charges 50% of the regular room rate for 'day use'.